# Are there any Netbooks powerful enough for moderate C++ compilation?

Tags: c++, hardware

I've tried a few Asus Ones, and found that even switching between multiple windows could take seconds. Is there anything powerful enough in that form factor for C++ programmers to build small to moderate size projects?

Comment: It's all a matter of time... it just depends on how much time you are willing to spend waiting. Perhaps `distcc` is an option for you?

Comment: This is too subjective. What's your budget? What is "small to medium"? What do you consider to be reasonably build times?

Comment: Are you sure they had enough memory installed? Not sure how much VC++ and GCC expect, but it's something to be scientific about.

Comment: There are "regular" spec notebooks in that form factor that should have no problem doing what you want.  They are not, alas, in the same price range.

Comment: Asus Ones?  Did you mean Acer Ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also give it a qualified yes.

What OS you use may matter a lot. I have Kubuntu on a HP 2140 netbook with only 1 gb of ram and the usual Asus N270 cpu. And it is actually rather snappy for window or desktop switches etc under KDE 4.3.

Compile-times are ok but I am spoiled by better machines at the office or even at home.  But I got this for the form factor and I take it with me while commuting. I mostly edit, write docs, etc pp while I am on the train and then commit back to SVN at the other end.  That works well for me, including the occassional `make` or `make check`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what compiler and editor/IDE you decide to use. The wimpiest Netbook is still a killer machine compared to what we used 20 or even 10 years ago. One of the easiest routes to better performance is to use an older editor/IDE (the compiler itself will probably be all right). Of course, we expected slower compilation back then too, but even so a minute to switch between windows would have been excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the HP Mini note? [Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001R9YRNO)

You could also try to compile with the Nice command, which will supposedly only do intensive things during the moments when your not using your computer much.

Comment: So anything with an i5 Intel, like a Thinkpad X series or T410 sounds like it would be more than enough?

Answer (score 0):

I have an eeepc and it's *okay* for compilation. I definitely wouldn't want to compile a complete Boost build on it. It works, but you're kind of slumming it. P4 speed, slow hard drive, small amount of RAM... less everything.

Answer (score -1):

A low-quality netbook has more resources and capabilities than my development workstations did a decade ago.  What you will need, however, is RAM.  If you try to do too many things at a time on one of these things you will swap like crazy because modern software and modern operating systems are written by lazy, slack developers who think RAM is a limitless resource.  Alternatively you can boost your RAM.  My wife's netbook got boosted to 1GB before the unit was even taken home and it's not at all bad.